# Keep getting this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium

I created a function that tries to get searched information from google but instead of opening the browser it should print the result but i keep getting this error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

this is my function:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1024x768")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",chrome_options = chrome_options)

def search(searchQuery):
driver.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + searchQuery)
answer = driver.execute_script("""return 
document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0],arguments[1]);""", 350, 230).text
    searchQuery = searchQuery.replace(' ','+')
return answer
```

Comment: at which line is error returned?

Comment: This means that `document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0],arguments[1]);""", 350, 230)` is returning `None`. Your code needs to be prepared for that.

Comment: it is returned at line 11